# NFC stopped to detect any tag in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, nfc, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am writing an app with ionic.

It depends on NFC tag scans. With my developer phone, i was developing for 1 month now. And it just stopped working from 1 day to an other.

- No changes to permissions.
- logcat does not throw any nfc service errors.
- The nfc plugin (ngCordovaNFC) does successfully attach the nfc listener, no errors.
- NFC is active
- No android updates available

But the phone seems not to detect anything. Not even the default android feedback (sound+vibration) does appear.

We already reverted all changes since the last known working build, no result.

Ask if you need any logs

Comment: Did you try a different phone?

Comment: It doesnt work on my and my colleges phone

Comment: Did you try a different tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by users expecting that devices keep their full functionality after removing significant parts of the device hardware. Hence this is not related to programming issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we found it by ourself.

The problem: We changed the battery of the smartphone.

**Changing the battery can cause nfc to stop from working. (Tested on samsung)**

Reason:

The NFC detector directly sticks on the battery. Sound crazy stupid, but they really did it. 
If you want to replace the battery with a stronger one and still be able to use NFC, check if the battery has the label "Near Field Communication"